# "Was" vs "Would + verb" when writing about the past?

Tags: grammar

So for some context, I'm writing for a history class assignment for the 1930s, but what I'm interested in is the usage of would and was here. I noticed I used "would + verb" many times in my writing, not really thinking about it. I think I may have used it too much.
For example:

"Even during this time, movies were relatively cheap for the struggling population and would become a new, popular form of entertainment."

and

"Photographers would be hired by government agencies for documentary purposes."

My question is this: in both of these examples, is it preferable to replace "would become" and "would be hired" by "became" and "were hired" respectively, and also, would using "would" like this too much be too repetitive for some people?

I'm not in dire need of an answer or something, I'm just curious and couldn't find an answer that quite matched this context.

Comment: These are two different senses of _would_; the first sentence is a "future-in-the-past" _would_, and the second is a repetitive generic, like _He would strap a turnip to his belt whenever he went out._ In the first sentence, whether you use _would_  depends on whether you want the reader to slice up the past into the initial period and the later, future-in-the-past period, or whether you want the two clauses to share the same time period. In the second sentence it doesn't make any difference, because the simple past tense is generic anyway.

Comment: Wow, thank you! It's nice to have that clarification on something I never really thought about.